# How to implement continuous scroll using Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium in Python, I would like to load the entirety of a JS generated list from this webpage: https://partechpartners.com/companies. There is a 'LOAD MORE' button at the bottom.

The code I've written to press the button (it just does it once currently, I know I'll need to extend it to be able to do it multiple times with a `while`):

```
from selenium import webdriver #The Selenium webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, WebDriverException
from time import sleep

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://partechpartners.com/companies'

driver.get(url)

sleep(2)

load_more = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[ text() = "LOAD MORE"]')

sleep(2)

try:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(load_more).click(load_more).perform()
    print("Element was clicked")
except Exception as e:
    print("Element wasn't clicked")
```

The code returns `Element was clicked`. However, when I add the following code to the bottom of the above script I only get 30 items returned, which is the number if the button hadn't been clicked, and the relative Xpath is the same for the elements pre and post button click, so I know it's not that:

```
len(driver.find_elements('xpath','//h2'))
```

I've also tried commenting out `chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")` to see if it works not asa headless browser and to follow the clicks. An accept cookies button appears that I can't get rid of, but that doesn't seem to matter because it still returns elements when I run the script above. What could I do to ensure the webdriver browser is actually loading the page?

Answer (score 0):

You get same results as far as you don't wait for anything after click directly.

In your case you can pay attention what is happening after scroll:

- Load more button changes it's location
- Amount of items on the increased
- When all items are loaded, button is disappeared

So, after click you can wait for amount items to be increased or button to change it's location (or for both conditions)

And repeat that in `while` loop until load more button is disappeared.

Example with location:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

chrome_options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

def wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(element):
    initial_location = element.location
    previous_location = initial_location
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 1:
        current_location = element.location
        if current_location != previous_location:
            previous_location = current_location
            start_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.4)

def get_shadow_root(element):
    return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)

url = 'https://partechpartners.com/companies'

driver.get(url)
timeout = 20
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)

#accept consent
shadow_host = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'usercentrics-root')))
shadow_container = get_shadow_root(shadow_host).find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid=uc-app-container]')
WebDriverWait(shadow_container, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid=uc-accept-all-button]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'usercentrics-root')))

#scroll logic
load_more_xpath = "//*[text()='LOAD MORE']"
load_more = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, load_more_xpath)))

while(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, load_more_xpath)) > 0):
    wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(load_more)
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(load_more).click(load_more).perform()

titles = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[id*=id-] h2')))
for title in titles:
    print(title.text)
```